# CSS overlaying SmartGWT style

Tags: css, performance, gwt, smartgwt

The css of my application is overlaying some style from [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/) and turning its perfomance really down.

If I run my application with the css file, it too slow, and I can't even hover the mouse over ListGrid widget. However if I take the css file off, it's performance is OK.

If I remove `ListGrid` and let the css file in the application performance is OK too.

Is there some way to identify how my CSS file is overlaying the [SmartGWT](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/) style? Or maybe someway to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "WWW debuger" Inspect Element in Chrome or Inspect Element in Firebug in Firefox. In the right panel you have styles part where you will style used for your widget and file name.
This way you can easly check which property from your CSS overrites the smartGWT one.